# problem with VBA apostrophes

Tags: excel, vba

Single line of code is causing my application to stop working - I think that the problem is with the apostrophes (maybe wrong escape):

```
.Formula = "=IF(AND(" 'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ">=1;"'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & "<=4);"'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ";0)"
```

When I try to enter the "' sequence VBA automatically puts a space between " and ' making the latter appear as comment.  What is wrong - do I need to use escape character here?  If yes how to code it.  I get an error 1004 Application of object-defined error.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape double quotes in VBA by putting 2 double quotes, like so:

```
""
```

You can also explicitly call `Chr(34)` to put in double quotes, like so:

```
Debug.Print "The following is in double quotes: " & _
    chr(34) & "Inside double quotes" & chr(34)
```

I wasn't able to try out the following formula in Excel, but I think it should work:

```
.Formula = "=IF(AND(""Criterion""" & i & "!" & cellAdress & _
  ">=1;""Criterion""" & i & "!" & cellAdress & "<=4);""Criterion""" & _
  i & "!" & cellAdress & ";0)"
```